# How to create a read only document in latex?

Tags: pdf, latex, readonly

I am trying to generate read only pdf's with latex and I am having difficulty finding the best solution. I looked at pdftek but what are other options?

Answer (score 1):

If you want truly read-only pdf's you can do what law firms do and print out the document then scan it back to a pdf.

PDF is an open format and given the right tools you can take it apart and pull out any images and any text.  That being said you can add security permissions using the pdftk tool.  If you encrypt it you can set permissions (like disabling editing and disabling printing)

See [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) and [permissions](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-output-enc-perms) in the man page.